# ArrayList's toArray() Method not Working Properly

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

When looking through `ArrayList`'s methods, I saw a method called `toArray()`. I tried out this method using the following code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
// Assigning random elements to the ArrayList
int[] b = a.toArray();
```

However, this showed the following exception in the compiler:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: int[]
Found: java.lang.Object[]
```

The next thing I tried next is down-casting it to `int[]`

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
// Assigning random elements to the ArrayList
int[] b = (int[]) a.toArray();
```

This showed another error:

```
Cannot cast java.lang.Object[] to int[]
```

The last thing I tried is making it an `Integer[]` instead, and down-casting it to `Integer[]`

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
// Assigning random elements to the ArrayList
Integer[] b = (Integer[]) a.toArray();
```

This one compiled, but as soon as I ran it it produced `ClassCastException`. How do I use this `toArray()` method without errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` can only hold reference types (like `Integer`). `Integer` is a wrapper type. To convert a `List<Integer>` to an `int[]` there is an option using a `Stream` to map the `Integer` values to `int` and then collect to an `int[]`. Like,

```
int[] b = a.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all written in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])):

```
Integer[] b = a.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Comment: I tried changing this to `int[] b = (int[]) a.toArray(new int[0]);`, but it said there is no such method for primitive type arrays. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you dont need the cast Integer[] b = a.toArray(new Integer[0]);

Comment: @nishantc1527 the reason that you need to pass the stupid new Integer[0] thing is to make it invoke generic version of toArray and let it know which type it should return. Type inference doesn't work with primitive types, so new int[0] won't work.  Bottom line is that if you want type safety you should stay away from arrays.

Comment: @MK true (for both statements). I usually try to rework my data structures when I find myself needing to call `toArray()`. Especially for a list of boxed primitives where Java seems terribly cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer of @Matthieu, It seems you need to pass new `Integer[]`. Attaching an example [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-array-conversion-java-toarray-methods/) given in geeksforgeeks.

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[a.size()]; 
arr = a.toArray(arr);
```